# USB Function on PPC460GT

Tags: linux, usb, driver

As I know, on PPC460GT doesn't support for USB functions. But I saw in my PPC460GT, it has a FT313H Chip, a USB 2.0 Host Controller Device. Can anyone tell me what can I do to enable USB 2.0 function based on FT3131H Chip on my PPC460GT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know how you can communicate with this controller. If you have it on board then it has to be accessible somehow from CPU point of view - at some address. If you have address you can remap it for linux kernel and then you have access to it EHCI registers.

Comment: Thanks, but a problem is that my board is based on PPC and in its DTS doesn't define for this FT313H Chip, so I cannot use PLATFORM_DRIVER to define my resource for chip. So how can I do now?